# Help restore my boot record

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, windows-server-2008

My computer has two hard drives.  The primary drive is a dynamic disk with two partitions.  The secondary drive is a dynamic disk now booting Windows 2008 Server (because its the only install media I have).

The primary drive's first partition used to be my C drive with a shiny new Windows 7 Ultimate installation.  I used Acronis Disk Director to set the drives up as above.  Well, last night I decided to delete the secondary disk's partition to mirror one of the others.  I told DD to delete the partition, then committed the operation.

When it rebooted after deleting that partition, my computer came up with "Operating system not found."  My only recovery option was to install another Windows on the new partition.  I can see all of my files of the existing Windows 7 installation.

How can I restore the boot information of my machine so it boots off that Windows 7 partition?

Comment: The Windows installer is known to occasionally install the bootloader to a different disk than the installation by default, seemingly at random. -OR-, If you installed Server 2008 after Windows 7, it may have actually removed the bootloader installed by 7 and configured its own bootloader to serve both operating systems (only one Windows bootloader is necessary to start multiple Windows installs).

Comment: Well what happened is I had the three partitions, I deleted the one that spanned all of disk 2.  Then it couldn't find the operating system.

Comment: Right, I suspect the Windows bootloader had actually been installed to this partition, probably because of the Windows 2008 install (if I understand correctly that that happened before Windows 7 became unbootable).

Answer (score 2):

You can boot from the Windows 7 disk and select "Repair installation." Should repair your MBR.